# How can i add classes or objects to a list?

Tags: vb.net

Me and a friend are working on a text based game in VB.

```
Class CyberWare
        Public name, description As String
        Public unlocked As Boolean
        Public level, damage, chargeTimes, healing As Integer
    End Class
Dim obj As New CyberWare
```

```
Sub UnlockMantisBlades()
        player.UnlockedCyberWare.Add(obj)
        player.UnlockedCyberWare(0).name = "Mantis blades"
        player.UnlockedCyberWare(0).description = "Arm blades designed with lethality and concealment in mind. As effective as they are flashy."
        player.UnlockedCyberWare(0).damage = 50
End Sub
```

```
Public Structure PlayerBlueprint
        Public UnlockedCyberWare As List(Of CyberWare)
        Public hp, maxhp, cp, maxcp As Integer
        Public Sub constructplayer()
            hp = 75
            maxhp = 75
            cp = 50
            maxcp = 50
        End Sub
    End Structure
    Dim player As New PlayerBlueprint
    Sub construct()


        player.constructplayer()
        UnlockMantisBlades()
    End Sub
```

(construct is called in the main method)

we're encountering this error when adding the object to the list. we have tried adding (CyberWare)
[image]

please help :c

Comment: This is not related to your issue specifically but don't add an item to a list and then get the item back from the list multiple times to set its properties. Create the object and set its properties first, preferably using an object initialiser, then add it to the list last. Also, all those public members should absolutely be properties and not fields. The `UnlockedCyberWare` property should also be read-only, i.e. you can get the list to get and set items but you can't replace the list with a completely separate one.

Comment: The correct name for `Sub ConstructPlayer` is `Sub New`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public UnlockedCyberWare As List(Of CyberWare)
```

Should be

```
Public UnlockedCyberWare As New List(Of CyberWare)
```

Comment: Hi mate thanks for the answer. tried that and got an error, i think you can only use new if it is inside a subroutine, correct?

Tried to put inside the construct subroutine but obviously that gets lost when finished

Comment: @OliverLazarusKeene, the suggestion would work if `PlayerBlueprint` was a class rather than a structure. Do you have a good reason for it being a structure because it absolutely looks like it should be a class. You should generally only use a structure for small, immutable types.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you have, for no apparent reason, declared `PlayerBlueprint` as a structure rather than as a class. Structure members cannot be initialised where they are declared. That's the reason that you have that `constructplayer` method to initialise the `Integer` fields. If you're going to do it that way, you should be initialising the `List` field there too:

```vb
Public Sub constructplayer()
    UnlockedCyberWare = New List(Of CyberWare)
    hp = 75
    maxhp = 75
    cp = 50
    maxcp = 50
End Sub
```

The better solution would be to declare `PlayerBlueprint` as a class. You can then initialise each field where you declare it and get rid of that method. Using proper naming conventions and using properties rather than fields for public members, your code should look like this:

```vb
Public Class CyberWare
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property IsUnlocked As Boolean
    Public Property Level As Integer
    Public Property Damage As Integer
    Public Property ChargeTimes As Integer
    Public Property Healing As Integer
End Class

Public Class PlayerBlueprint
    Public ReadOnly Property UnlockedCyberWare As New List(Of CyberWare)
    Public Property Hp As Integer = 75
    Public Property MaxHp As Integer = 75
    Public Property Cp As Integer = 50
    Public Property MaxCp As Integer = 50
End Class
```

and then:

```vb
Sub UnlockMantisBlades()
    player.UnlockedCyberWare.Add(New CyberWare With {.Name = "Mantis blades",
                                                     .Description = "Arm blades designed with lethality and concealment in mind. As effective as they are flashy.",
                                                     .Damage = 50})
End Sub
```